# HTML not being filled with Angular data

Tags: angularjs

I have some Angular code where the API is called and I get the right data.

But then none of the variables are filled in the HTML.

I do not get any image or the loading button does not has the text.

I have been around this and can't find the answer.

Am I missing something on my $scope?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var application = angular.module('Application', []);

  application.service('ImageService', function ($http) {
    return {
      GetList: function (ipage) {
        return $http.get('api/images', { params: { ipage: ipage } });
      },
    }
  });

  application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService) {

    $scope = {
      images: [],
      loading: false,
      pages: { instagram: '12' }          
    }

    var load = function () {
      $scope.loading = true;
      ImageService.GetList($scope.pages.instagram)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.images = $scope.images.concat(data.Images)
          $scope.pages.instagram = data.NextInstagramPage;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
        .finally(function () {
          $scope.loading = false
        });;
    }

    $scope.loader = function () {
      return $scope.loading ? 'loading' : 'load more';
    }

    $scope.reload = function () {
      load();
    }

    load();

  });

</script>

<div data-ng-app="Application" data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">
  <div data-ng-repeat='image in images' class="image">
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
  <a href="" class="reload" data-ng-disabled={{loading}} data-ng-click="reload()">{{loader()}}</a>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you overwrite the `$scope` object completely when you assign to it new object like `$scope = {...};`. Instead you can extend scope with few additional properties:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    images: [],
    loading: false,
    pages: {
        instagram: '12'
    }
});
```

You could also set individual properties separately:

```
$scope.images: [];
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.pages = { instagram: '12' };
```

Comment: Is that the reason why sometimes i see $scope.model = {  images: [] , loading = fase, ... }? In this case how would I need to change my html?

Comment: What do you mean you see "$scope.model = { images: [] , loading = fase, ... }"?

Comment: I have seen in some controllers people wraping the properties into one object model instead of defining individual properties ... But i am not surf how to use the html in this case ... does this make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see. You can use model in this case  `data-ng-disabled="model.loading`, `ng-repeat='image in model.images'`, etc.

Comment: Its equal to defining properties individual or as a bunch of a new object.
Its just the prefered style of writing.
But you overwrote the complete $scope, that was the problem.

Comment: Yes, you can use both way, `$scope.model` just looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: Sorry but you is more common to use model or individual properties?

Comment: In your case it' better to use model.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your controller isn't inited rightly try

```
application.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', 'ImageService' ,function ImageController($scope, ImageService) { ...}]);
```

and your service the same:

```
application.service('ImageService',['$http', function ($http) {...}]);
```

Comment: Still does not work ... And are you sure you need those changes to the code? I had this working without those changes ... But I started to change some variables and then it stopped working ... I just can't find where the problem is now.